# Jquery context: parent of this

Tags: jquery

### HTML

I have this repeating HTML:

```
<section class="country">
    <header><h1 class="heading"><span>Belgium</span></h1></header>
    <div class="main" style="display: none;">
        <article class="shop">Some content here</article>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="country">
    <header><h1 class="heading"><span>Belgium</span></h1></header>
    <div class="main" style="display: none;">
        <article class="shop">Some content here</article>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="country">
    <header><h1 class="heading"><span>Belgium</span></h1></header>
    <div class="main" style="display: none;">
        <article class="shop">Some content here</article>
    </div>
</section>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.country .main').hide();
$('.country header').click(function() {
  $('.country .main').slideToggle(500);
});
```

### Question

How do I use context to slideToggle only the .main container closest to the clicked header, because now ALL .main containers expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).next().slideToggle(500);` instead:

```
$('.country .main').hide();
$('.country header').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PYPEw/)**

Answer (score 3):

use `$(this)`

```
 $(this).closest('.country').find('.main').slideToggle(500);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/As8jr/)**